# Malloc error when reading from file

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have a file with each line of strings is in this format

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
....
```

I need to extract the strings in third column. The code I've written so far is

```
    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    assert(fp && "checkpoint file not found  \n");

    char **data = (char **) malloc(sizeof (char*) * lines ); // lines=100
    size_t i = 0;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1){
        size_t l = strlen(line);

        char value[256];
        sscanf( line, "%s %s %s", field, tmp, value); // field stores 'key1', tmp stores '+', value stores 'value1'

        data[i] = value;
        i++;
        printf("%s \n", value);
        // printf("%s %s\n", value, data[i]); -- when this line is uncommented, it leads to a seg-fault.
    }
    fclose(fp);


      for (int i=0; i < lines; ++i)
        free(data[i]);
      free(data);
```

I get an error "malloc error for object .., pointer being freed is not allocated".

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: You didn't show any code calling `free`, which the error message seems to have come from. We also don't know what `tmp`, `field` and some other things are. Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `data[i] = value;` is copying a pointer to the same input string whose content gets overwritten in every loop. Try the non-standard `data[i] = strdup(value);` which might fix it. The function `strdup` calls `malloc` so you'll have to `free` each element of the array of pointers later.

Comment: is it segfault, "malloc error for object .., pointer being freed is not allocated", or both alternatively with a 43% probability for the segfault ? :) anyway your code is very very buggy.

Comment: @WeatherVane +1 if OP tries to free the pointers of the array, that could explain a lot because freeing auto (invalidated) memory is rarely appreciated by the system.

Comment: I free the  data[][], I've modified the code

Comment: @kris and that is why we always ask for [mcve]...

Comment: In C, it is not appropriate to use assert to check the return value of a function.  `assert` is for things which are logically necessary.   `fopen` can return NULL, and it is not correct to `assert` otherwise.

Comment: Allocate and copy: `data[i] = strdup(value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct cause of the observed error is:

```
char value[256];
//....
data[i] = value;
```

and later (in a subsequent loop):

```
free(data[i]);
```

You are freeing the statically allocated array.

You want:

```
char *value=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
```

I know `sizeof(char)==1` by definition. It's just good practice.

Comment: Thanks, accepting this answer as it has example to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I see it is, before

```
  printf("%s %s\n", value, data[i]);
```

this line, you're doing `i++` which changes the value of `i`. Then `data[i]` points to an uninitialized memory. Passing that as argument to `%s` causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

[*Edit:*]

Then again, you're doing

```
 free(data[i]);
```

whereas, `data[i]` is not a pointer returned by a memory allocator function. That's another cause for UB.

That said,

- You never bound `i` with `lines`, which is the one-over the maximum allowed index. You need to keep a check such that `i < lines` satisfies at all times.
- You did not check for the success of `sscanf()` call, failure to this call may lead to reading of invalid memory too.
- [See this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917). You should also check for the success of `malloc()` before dereferencing the returned pointer.

Comment: Very true, I was that too. But isn't there other errors? like number of lines too low (ok: telepathy :))? because the "pointer being freed" is probably not because of that error. Well, you never know with UB :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Does the expansion cover this, or you meant anything else? :)

Comment: your answer is well documented (and you got my vote). I was just wondering if OP gets segfault or "malloc error for object .., pointer being freed is not allocated", which could only occur when freeing memory, and probably not because of a printf present or not. Memory corruption + free can lead to that all right.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Agreed, but with this snippet, above is what we got. :)

Comment: Weather Vane has a point when he says that OP puts a local array in the pointer array (and the same array!!) so probably crashes when attempting to free the pointers in the array when they haven't been allocated in the firtst place.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Very probable, my answer just follows the comment present in OP's snippet, whatever is shown here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and there you go...check OP's edit. :)

Comment: crystal ball strikes again :) also `data` isn't even valid memory since it copied an auto variable which went out of scope. You can add that (but I cannot upvote once more :))

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `char value[256]` reserves some room on the function stack. Your `data[i]` keeps pointing to that same place on the stack, for different `i`. Note that you have a possible overflow problem on the stack when `value` is too small, unless there is a fixed limit to its size. This stack region is not alloced so cannot be freed, hence the error.

A consequence is that `data[i]` gets overwitten by all further lines after its first asignment. You get a (non-freeable) pointer to the same region every time. You need to copy that value to tyour own pointer:. What you also need to do is free the variable `line` in the end (as it gets a malloc-ed pointer value and gets realloc-ed to make it fit the line.), and for every line do a `malloc` to make a pointer to *copy* `value` into and set `data[i]` to that new pointer. So there are all sorts of problems in your code.

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks for a detailed explanation.